# OpenCTI API Calls

Tags: appexchange, javascript-remoting, app, opencti

Do the calls made by client App developed using OpenCTI framework are counted against consumer's API limit.

How about remote JavaScript methods that invoke Controller method in an App package ?

Answer (score 1):

All instances where Salesforce API is invoked whether via javascript,  remoting, external tools (OpenCTI, data loader) are counter against API limits usage.

Only following are exmpted:-

1. Outbound messages
2. Apex callouts

for more details refer:- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm